# Inserting into n-child tree in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, insertion

I am trying to implement a tree for the travelling salesperson problem. My particular tree has 5 destinations which are fully connected to each other.

One of the destinations is guaranteed to always be the starting destination and that you are only allowed to visit each destination once with the exception of the starting destination which you have to return to (ie if you have [1,2,3,4,5] with 1 the starting destination, a possible sequence of moves would be 1-3-5-2-4-1)

I tried implementing a tree in python with the following code (I brute forced it since I know the maximum depth is going to be 5).

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value, city, children = [None, None, None, None]):
        self.value = value
        self.city = city
        self.children = children

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,value,city):
        newNode = Node(value,city)
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = newNode
        else:
            self._insert(1, newNode)

    def _insert(self,depth, newNode):

        if depth is 1:
            for x in range(0,4):
                if self.root.children[x] is None:
                    self.root.children[x] = newNode
                    return
                elif self.root.children[3] is not None:
                    self._insert(2, newNode)
                    return

        if depth is 2:
            for x in range(0,4):
                for y in range(0,3):
                    if self.root.children[x].children[y] is None:
                        self.root.children[x].children[y] = newNode
                        return
                    elif self.root.children[3].children[2] is not None:
                        self._insert(3, newNode)
                        return

        if depth is 3:
            for w in range(0,4):
                for x in range(0,3):
                    for y in range(0,2):
                        if self.root.children[w].children[x].children[y] is None:
                            self.root.children[w].children[x].children[y] = newNode
                            return
                        elif self.root.children[3].children[2].children[1] is not None:
                            self._insert(4,newNode)
                            return
        if depth is 4:
            for w in range(0,4):
                for x in range(0,3):
                    for y in range(0,2):
                        for z in range(0,1):
                            if self.root.children[w].children[x].children[y].children[z] is None:
                                self.root.children[w].children[x].children[y].children[z] = newNode
                                return
                            elif self.root.children[3].children[2].children[1].children[0] is not None:
                                self._insert(5,newNode)
                                return
        if depth is 5:
            for w in range(0,4):
                for x in range(0,3):
                    for y in range(0,2):
                        for z in range(0,1):
                            for u in range(0,1):
                                if self.root.children[w].children[x].children[y].children[z].children[u] is None:
                                    self.root.children[w].children[x].children[y].children[z].children[u] = newNode
                                    return
                                elif self.root.children[3].children[2].children[1].children[0].children[0] is not None and w is 3 and x is 2 and y is 1 and z is 0 and u is 0:
                                    print "The table is full"


    def delete(self):
        self.root = None

x = Tree()
x.insert(0, "Pretoria")
x.insert(60, "Johannesburg")
x.insert(1200, "Cape Town")
x.insert (600, "Durban")
x.insert(400, "Bloemfontein")
x.insert(1400, "Port Elizabeth")
```

My root and first level populate correctly but all the children nodes of the second, third, fourth and fifth level all populate exactly the same as the first level. When I checked their memory, they all populated the exact same memory space and I have no idea why. This happens when the following line of code runs:

```
x.insert(1400, "Port Elizabeth")
```

The tree for some reason is fully populated at this point despite only having 5 entries.

I tried using pointers at first but the same issue crops up.

Long story short, how would one go about inserting into an n-ary tree with decreasing n as you increase in depth?

This particular tree has the following attributes:

- Root: 4 children per node (1 node with 4 children)
- Level 1: 3 children per node (4 nodes with 3 children)
- Level 2: 2 children per node (12 nodes with 2 children)
- level 3: 1 child per node (24 nodes with 1 child)
- level 4: 1 child per node (24 nodes with 1 child) (this is final destination in the TSP)